# MacOs prevent wifi disconnection

Tags: macos

I'm new to Mac. Currently using Apple M1 Sonoma 14.1. How do you guys prevent your laptop disconnect from wifi during screen off?

Scenario: During a lecture, sometime you are to focus hearing the lecture, but I'm not always looking at my Mac, sometime it keep disconnect from wifi if I want to search for something.

I'm using `caffeinate` for now. but I have to do it manually, and control+c on terminal to stop it.

I have set Wake for network access to `always`

is there any better way?

Comment: set it for 1 hour or more with  caffeinate -t 3600